# Primefaces run java script onComplete/onClick

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a p:command button as shown below.

```
<p:commandButton id="settings" ajax="false" onComplete="window.alert('sometext');"      value="#{messages.settings}"
styleClass="cancelButton" style="font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica, Geneva; font-size: 10pt; width: 90px;" /></td>
```

I want this button to run a java-script onComplete or onClick but I can not get any of them to work. I actually want it to open a popup but here I have tried with an easier script to just do an alert. But this does not work either. Nothing happens at all.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First : there is no capitals in `onxxx` (where xxx is  *start* / *complete* / *success*)

Since you set `ajax="false"` your button won't do any ajax , which means that `onstart` / `oncomplete` / `onsuccess` won't be triggered at all

Use `onclick="alert('wow')"`

If you will remove the `ajax="false"` you will be able to use `oncomplete="alert('wow')"`

Comment: The ajax=false is just a paste error from me. I actually have it removed in my xhtml page. So even if I change oncomplete to lower-case and remove ajax=false it still does not work.

Comment: is it inside `h:form` ? show more code , how about `onclick="alert('wow')"` does it work?

Comment: Yes I have, I however found <ui:composition> in the code and I do not think that this should be there? When remove that it seems like it is working better, havent got the alert yet thou. I'm in the middle of migrating some very old xhtml to jsf2 and primefaces so there is some more stuff in the way.

Comment: I have fixed the new problems that I got when I removed the ui:composition now. However I'm back where I started with no alert showing. In my xhtml I have <h:head> and <h:body> and <h:form> form and body are the ones around my p:commandbutton. And I have the 4 needed xmlns found at http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html. Any new idea how to fix it?