# firing JS code when file download is finished (java server faces)

Tags: javascript, jsf

I woudl like to fire some IS code after the download is finished
I am using jsf, not primefaces

```
 <h:commandButton value="Download" action="#{fileDownloadController.newDownloadXMLFile(editUDBean.mostRecentFile)}"  />
```

Any hints ?

Comment: There is no event for when files are downloaded, not sure how you would do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was looking for an alternative to primefaces, because a a bug on the PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop), it won't activate the stop function, anyways, thanks

Comment: Many Faces (RichFaces, PrimeFaces, ...) have `oncomplete` tag which can be used for this purpose.

Comment: I tried priemfaces and it does not seem to work, thanks for having taken the time to answer !

Comment: Check out this answer http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19672#p67522 might help using primefaces download

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706432/primefaces-run-java-script-oncomplete-onclick)